# How to update current row with next in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have nodes with `status = 0` which `updated_at` column needs to be updated with next rows `created_at` column.

[image]

Something like this:

```
UPDATE node_status AS s SET s.updated_at = (
    SELECT created_at
    FROM node_status
    WHERE id > s.id AND node_id = s.node_id
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE s.node_id = 1811
```

Currently I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: And what is wrong with your current query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen http://i.imgur.com/7S5ZNzi.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try rewriting your correlated update using an inner join:

```
UPDATE node_status t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, node_id,
        (SELECT created_at FROM node_status t
         WHERE t.id > s.id AND t.node_id = s.node_id
         ORDER BY t.id LIMIT 1) AS created_at
    FROM node_status s
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.node_id = t2.node_id
SET
    t1.updated_at = t2.created_at
WHERE
    t1.node_id = 1811;
```

Note that I added an `ORDER BY` clause to the `LIMIT` subquery, because this appears to be your intended logic.  In general, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless.

Comment: Error: Unknown column `s.id` in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Make a function with node_id as parameter and use `SELECT INTO` to store the result of: `SELECT created_at FROM node_status WHERE id > s.id AND node_id = s.node_id LIMIT 1` into a variable, then use your `UPDATE` setting the variable as your value.

You may want to ensure an order in that `SELECT` otherwise weird things may happen.

Then call the function, of course.